# Issues with calculating standard deviation in matlab

Tags: matlab, std

I have this huge sparse matrix of size **7 million by 1000**. I want to calculate the standard deviation of each column. If I do it column by column like `std(data(:,i)` and loop over each column it is fine.

But if I try to do it at once `std(data)`, it freezes and crashes.

What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Do something in between: divide the matrix into vertical chunks, with as much width as your computer supports. For each chunk call `std`, and loop over chunks. Thus you won't have to loop so many times

Comment: Does `mean(data)` also freeze?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do it is to use matlabs "std" function, in my simple tests (size(A) = [1e3,1e3]), it is about 10 times faster. The downside is that, as you have noticed, have to parse the entire matrix to the function. This takes memory, which you likely do not have.

The solution is, as Luis Mendo have suggested in the comment, to do something in between. Namely that you divide your matrix into larger chunks and then parse these chunks to the function. e.g.

```
A = randn(1e3);
chunkSize = 100;
res = zeros(1,1e3);
for i = 1:length(A)/chunkSize;
    res((i-1)*chunkSize+1:i*chunkSize) = std(A((i-1)*chunkSize+1:i*chunkSize));
end
```